# Deep linking in Flutter and iOS with variable host

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How can I open my app from a link in iOS from any host as long as the url ends with some extension?
I'd like to open links with my app that looks like:

{http or https}://{any.random.host}/{custom/fixed/path}

The host is my main problem here, as I can't control where the host will be (and I know there will be more than one), **I cannot have a fixed host** in my config files for iOS or Android. Also, **I cannot have an scheme different from http or https** since I need that if the app is not available, it should points and opens the website instead.

In Android I can do something as follow in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="false">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="*"
        android:path="/myapp.app"
    />
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And it works pretty well, I can intercept any url as long as it ends with /myapp.app and then, I can open my app. Now, in iOS I have problems implementing DeepLinking, the example I got from [this post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283) says that I need to edit my Info.plist, which it looks like:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>*/myapp.app</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>http</string>
            <string>https</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But this isn't working, it even isn't working with a normal BundleURLName (like, for example, www.myapp.app), I think it's because I can't use http and https for Deeplinking in iOS but I'm not sure.

Comment: have you fixed this issue please tell me I am also stuck with same issue

Comment: @Monty I didn't find any solution :/, so I opted to use a mix of Firebase Dynamic Linking and Universal Links...